# Dynamic height box inside a fixed height box

Tags: css, height

I have a div with fixed height. Inside this div I have one element at the top with a variable height (it could be 200px to 400px) and other elements with fixed height. The precise height of the element with variable height will be known after the dom is loaded.

Is there a way to adapt the others elements to this variable height with CSS?

[image: example]

Comment: Do you have an example of your code?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wah9af9e/1/

Comment: Where did box b go? (on the right side of your illustration)

Comment: When the height of the first DIV increase I would like to hide the box b. The question is: how can I handle a variable div inside a fixed height DIV without break the layout or have blank spaces?